# Difference Between One Sample vs Two Sample chi-squared test

Tags: chi-squared-test

I'm working on a project that involves finding p-values for data using a chi-squared test. I've written up code for it. Unfortunately, I seem to be trapped in a loop:

- I email in my code
- I'm told "This is code for a one sample chi-squared test, you need to do a two sample chi-squared test
- I look up two sample chi-squared test online. It looks exactly like what I already have.
- Repeat, repeat, repeat

Here is my code (in Python). gens is a list of integers: 0, 1 or 2. phens is a list of integers: 0 or 1. The goal is to determine whether individuals with phen=0 have different gens compared to individuals with phen=1.

```
def pValues(gens,phens):
    observed=[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]​
    n0=0​
    n1=0​
    gen0=0​
    gen1=0​
    gen2=0​
    for i in range(len(gens)):​
        if phens[i]==0:​
            n0+=1​
            if gens[i]==0:​
                gen0+=1​
                observed[0]+=1​
            elif gens[i]==1:​
                gen1+=1​
                observed[1]+=1​
            elif gens[i]==2:​
                gen2+=1​
                observed[2]+=1​
        elif phens[i]==1:​
            n1+=1​
            if gens[i]==0:​
                gen0+=1​
                observed[3]+=1​
            elif gens[i]==1:​
                gen1+=1​
                observed[4]+=1​
            elif gens[i]==2:​
                gen2+=1​
                observed[5]+=1​
    expected=[n0*gen0,n0*gen1,n0*gen2,n1*gen0,n1*gen1,n1*gen2]​
    for i in range(6):​
        expected[i]=float(expected[i])/len(gens)​
    chisum=0​
    for k in range(6):​
        if expected[k]!=0:​
            chisum+=((observed[k]-expected[k])**2)/expected[k]​
        else:​
            chisum='Infinity'​
            break​
    if chisum!='Infinity':​
        pvalue=1-chi2.cdf(chisum,2)​
    else:​
        pvalue=0​
    return pvalue
```

So for each i=0,1,2 and j=0,1, the expected number of individuals with gen=i and phen=j is #(gen=i) * #(phen=j)/#(total). Isn't this what the two-sample chi squared test calls for? What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Who is telling you this is for a one-sample Chi-Square test? By virtue of this being dependent on two outcomes, this is a test for statistical independence, i.e. a "two-sample" chi-square test. Try testing you function against the chi-square test in scipy by following https://codingdisciple.com/chi-squared-python.html

Comment: A student of my supervisor... English is not his first language; but here's his email reply to me:

First, your derivation is right.
Second, we should recognize that the test is a two-sample test, because there is no underline true distribution, all values are calculated from the data.
Third, the observed vector in your code is one of the two samples.
Fourth, the expected vector in your code, which is regarded as the underline true expectation by you, should be another sample.

Comment: Final, these two samples, the expected and observed vectors in your code, should be conducted a two-sample chi-squared test, rather than the one sample test you adopted.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure I understand the issue they see, other than how you defined things. I have uploaded an answer below with some alterations that they may find acceptable. Or maybe not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have altered the code some to make it clear that you are creating your expected values from the row totals times the column totals, divided by the overall count. Good luck.

```
def pValues(gens,phens):
        observed=[0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]​
        n=len(gens)
        phen0=0​
        phen1=0​
        gen0=0​
        gen1=0​
        gen2=0​

        for i in range(len(gens)):​
            if phens[i]==0:​
                phen0+=1​
                if gens[i]==0:​
                    gen0+=1​
                    observed[0]+=1​
                elif gens[i]==1:​
                    gen1+=1​
                    observed[1]+=1​
                elif gens[i]==2:​
                    gen2+=1​
                    observed[2]+=1​
            elif phens[i]==1:​
                phen1+=1​
                if gens[i]==0:​
                    gen0+=1​
                    observed[3]+=1​
                elif gens[i]==1:​
                    gen1+=1​
                    observed[4]+=1​
                elif gens[i]==2:​
                    gen2+=1​
                    observed[5]+=1​

        expected=[phen0*gen0/n,phen0*gen1/n,phen0*gen2/n,phen1*gen0/n,phen1*gen1/n,phen1*gen2/n]​

        if 0 in expected:
            chisum = 'Infinity'
        else:
            chisum=0​
            for k in range(6):​
                chisum+=((observed[k]-expected[k])**2)/expected[k]​

        if chisum!='Infinity':​
            pvalue=1-chi2.cdf(chisum,2)​
        else:​
            pvalue=0​

        return pvalue
```